# AJAX PHP FORMULARIOS

Tags: php, ajax

Hols!
Estoy tratando de hacer un Formulario que valide el email, es algo sencillo y aún así no me funciona. me dice que hay un erro con el js, soy nueva utilizando ajax y todavía me cuesta
 me dice

> ```
> ajax-form.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
> at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (ajax-form.js:28)
> ```

mi js

```
document.getElementById("cambiar").addEventListener("click",cambiar);
document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click",enviar);

function cambiar(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("parrafo").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
}

function enviar(){
    var su_correo = "correo="+document.getElementById("correo").value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST","login.php");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(su_correo);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

mi php

```
<?php

include("db.php");
$db_con = new PDO('mysqli:host=localhost;dbname=user_login', 'root', '');

if (filter_var($_POST['correo'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo 'Correo Válido';
}
else {
    echo 'No Válido';
}
?>
```

mi html

```
  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
     <p id="parrafo">¿Cuál es tu correo?</p>
    <button id="cambiar">¿Disculpa?</button>
    <input type="email" id="correo"> 
    <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
    <p id=”respuesta”></p>
    <script src="js/ajax-form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Esto me sirve para hacer el login, muchas gracias

Comment: Segun el error parece que no está recogiendo bien el elemento con `id = 'respuesta'`

Comment: Reemplaza las comillas torcidas `<p id=”respuesta”></p>`  por comillas normales `<p id="respuesta"></p>`

Answer (score 1):

Las comillas que estás usando para el elemento `p` no son válidas

```
<p id=”respuesta”></p>
```

Debiera ser

```
<p id="respuesta"></p>
```